# How to run SQL command in CLI for Sybase 11

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm tasked with supporting a production Sybase 11 Database, without using Sybase Central how do you run commands from the CLI, I want to do the same things I can go in mysql, show databases; selects edit items in tables. 
Thanks in advance, doesn't seem like there's alot of information out there. Regards Mark

Comment: What is Sybase 11 Database? Is it old Sybase SQL Server version 11.0? Or is this SAP's SQL Anywhere 11? Please provide a result for select @@version.

Comment: I can't even run select on the CLI, the only way is through Sybase Central. I'll run it tomorrow and see if I can get a version. Thanks

Comment: This is SQL Anywhere 11.

Comment: Please remove the sybase-ase tag, since it is not ASE.

Comment: There is a command line client : http://www.freetds.org/userguide/ , but it is very limited (IIRC 1 query per session; IIRC works over ODBC) It should work for both Sybase and MS-sql(which was based on sybase; including the protocol)